Hardware broken after kernel upgrade
I have a problem with
VL805/806 xHCI USB 3.0 Controller (rev 01)
After upgrade to 24.04. It worked with boot option iommu=soft on 22.04. New kernel version is 6.8.0-40. Can I fix it without downgrading to an old kernel
